Find two tangent points for given circle and two points inside the circle , Lua
I have two Points A and B (given with coordinates ax, ay and bx, by).
This two points are inside of given Circle C (given with coordinates cx, cy and radius cr).
How to find points T1 and T2?
Points T1 and T2 must be on the tangent between circle C and imaginary circles D1 and D2 (both are on the points A and B).

Example values:
A (30, 30)
B (40, 20)
C (50, 50, 40)

right solution:
T1 (28.6061, 16.202)
T2 (87.3939, 35.798)

I've started with the middle point M:
mx, my = (ax+bx)/2, (ay+by)/2
The perpendicular line to line AB:
m1x, m1y = mx + (ay-my), my - (ax-mx)
m2x, m2y = mx + (by-my), my - (bx-mx)


And how to get the circles D1 and D2?

How do I ask and answer homework questions?

I am old, but the math answers from https://math.stackexchange.com/ is not easy for me, sorry. It's not a homework, I'm trying to make Voronoi Diagram with round sweep line, I have some troubles there and in google was no simple solution.

My advice is to write out the equations which express the constraints, and then look for ways to solve for T1 and T2. An algebraic solution would be great but maybe a numerical solution works for practical purposes. As it stands it looks to me like you've skipped a step -- I don't see the constraints, and instead you are going directly for a solution. Sometimes that's OK but speaking for myself, I try to work it out one step at a time, so I recommend that to you too.

Not really a Lua question

You are almost there, however the algebra is complicated here - so I'll give you just an idea, but not a complete answer. I'll consider a circle with the center in D1.
Note, that distance(A,D1) = distance(B,D1) = distance(D1,T1). You can find a unit vector N, perpendicular to the line AB, and express vector D1 in terms of the midpoint vector M and the vector N, multiplied by a scalar parameter t:
D1 = M + t*N                                        (1)

The distance(C,T1) is known to be equal to cr, and also it's equal to the sum:
distance(C,T1) = distance(C,D1) + distance(D1,T1) = cr

This can be rewritten as:
distance(C,M + t*N) + distance(A,M + t*N) = cr      (2)

This is an equation with a single unknown variable t, which can be solved algebraically (it's not easy) - its solutions will give you two points D1 and D2.
Another option is to solve this equation numerically, incrementing the parameter t by small value and computing a result in a loop. This kind of solvers used to be available in various programming languages (not sure about Lua).

ADDITION #1. I used C++ and two open-source libraries to verify the idea above (I don't know Lua). Hopefully you'll be able to convert my code to Lua - it's elementary geometry plus finding a root of a function using bisection method. The code is below:
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/math/tools/roots.hpp>
#include <CGAL/Simple_cartesian.h>

namespace bmt = boost::math::tools;

using Kernel = CGAL::Simple_cartesian<double>;
using Circle = Kernel::Circle_2;
using Point = Kernel::Point_2;
using Vector = Kernel::Vector_2;

// ------ return vector, corresponding to the point P
Vector toVector(Point const& P)
{
  return P - CGAL::ORIGIN;
}

// ------ return unit vector, corresponding to the vector V 
Vector unitVector(Vector const& V)
{
  return V / std::sqrt(V.squared_length());
}

// ------ return the end point of the vector with origin in (0,0)
Point endPoint(Vector const& V)
{
  return CGAL::ORIGIN + V;
}

// ------ return the point of intersection of the circle C and its radius, passing through the point P 
Point boundaryPoint(Circle const& C, Point const& P)
{
  return C.center() + unitVector(P - C.center()) * std::sqrt(C.squared_radius());
}

// ------ given points and circle
Point const A{30, 30};
Point const B{40, 20};
Circle const C{{50, 50}, 40 * 40};

// ------ computed midpoint and perpendicular unit vector
auto const M = (toVector(A) + toVector(B)) / 2.0;
auto const N = unitVector((A - B).perpendicular(CGAL::CLOCKWISE)); 

// ------ the root of this function is used to find the center of the circle
double func(double const X)
{
  auto const D = endPoint(M + X * N);
  return
  (
    std::sqrt(CGAL::squared_distance(C.center(), D))
    +
    std::sqrt(CGAL::squared_distance(A, D))
    -
    std::sqrt(C.squared_radius())
  );
}

// ------ this function stops the root search when the root is found
bool tolerance(double const L, double const R)
{
  return (R - L) <= 0.00001;
}

// ------ the Boost Math Tools function 'bisect' is used to find the root in the interval [MIN,MAX] 
Point boundaryPoint(double const MIN, double const MAX)
{
  auto const t = bmt::bisect(func, MIN, MAX, tolerance);
  auto const D = endPoint(M + t.first * N);
  return boundaryPoint(C, D);
}

int main()
{
  auto const T1 = boundaryPoint(-50.0, 0.0);
  std::cout << T1.x() << '\t' << T1.y() << std::endl;
  auto const T2 = boundaryPoint(0.0, 50.0);
  std::cout << T2.x() << '\t' << T2.y() << std::endl;
}


Addition #2. This problem can be solved analytically, that is – without numerical methods. I’ll still use the parametric expression (1) for the point D1. The equation (2) can be elaborated a little bit further. Let’s find a point F, lying on the line, passing through points M and D1, and closest to the center C of the big circle. The vector C-F will be orthogonal to the unit vector N. Some notation:
a = half-length of the segment (A,B)
u = length of the segment (C,F)
v = length of the segment (M,F) 
R = radius of the big circle (= your cr) 

The segment (C,T1) is divided by the point D1 into two parts - (C,D1) and (D1,T1). The length of the segment (C,D1) is equal to sqrt(u^2 + (v-t)^2), and the length of the segment (D1,T1) is equal to the radius of the inscribed circle – that is sqrt(a^2 + t^2). So, the equation (2) becomes:
 sqrt(a^2 + t^2) + sqrt(u^2 + (v-t)^2) = R

We can try to solve this equation by hand, but it’s not easy. Fortunately, the symbolic algebra website "PolyMathLove.com" can solve it – please see here. However, I didn’t verify this solution.
